# Oracle REGEXP_SUBSTR but with multiple possibilities

Tags: python, sql, oracle

In Pandas there is a function called 'explode'
Which makes this possible

```
NAME | P_ID
------------
A    | L1147511
B    | L1124411;L1745552;L5231242
C    | L1124427,L1142322;L5223112
D    | L4715442 / L9914234
E    | L1147329 [L1147459 ( Test)]
```

Result should be:

```
NAME | P_ID
------------
A    | L1147511
B    | L1124411
B    | L1745552
B    | L5231242
C    | L1124427
C    | L1142322
C    | L5223112
D    | L4715442
D    | L9914234
E    | L1147329
E    | L1147459
```

Is there any possibility to do it with Oracle SQL? Or do I have to do it in Python?
Thanks in advance.

My SQL until now looks like this:

```sql
SELECT
    DISTINCT TRIM(NAME) AS NAME ,
    TRIM(P_ID) AS P_ID,
    regexp_substr(TRIM(P_ID), '^[Ll0-9]{8,8}', 1, 1) AS P_ID
FROM
    test_table
```

But it only extracts on of the IDS. The first one. Multiple are not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use below solution which takes advantage of the ***lateral inline view*** if you are running on **oracle 12c or higher** version.
[*more details*](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_I1E9BSYB6KU5OMELS6ZCKIP10.html)

```sql
SELECT 
    t.NAME,
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(t.P_ID, 'L[[:digit:]]+', 1, rws.lvl) AS P_ID
FROM
  test_table t
, lateral (
  select LEVEL lvl
  from dual
  connect by LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(t.P_ID, 'L[[:digit:]]+', 1, 'i')
  ) rws
ORDER BY NAME, P_ID;
```

[***demo***](https://dbfiddle.uk/qxBu3Oea)

Answer (score 1):

Sample table:

```
SQL> select * from test;

NAME P_ID
---- ------------------------------
A    L1147511
B    L1124411;L1745552;L5231242
C    L1124427,L1142322;L5223112
D    L4715442 / L9914234
E    L1147329 [L1147459 ( Test)]
```

Here's one option; read comments within code:

```
SQL> with
  2  temp as
  3    -- replace all "delimiters" with a comma
  4    (select name,
  5       regexp_replace(p_id, ';|/|\[|\(|\)|\]', ',') p_id
  6     from test
  7    ),
  8  temp_2 as
  9    -- split P_ID from TEMP into rows
 10    (select name,
 11       trim(regexp_substr(p_id, '[^,]+', 1, column_value)) p_id,
 12       column_value rn
 13     from temp cross join
 14       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 15                           connect by level <= regexp_count(p_id, ',') + 1
 16                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 17    )
 18  select name, p_id
 19  from temp_2
 20  where p_id is not null
 21  order by name, rn;
```

Result:

```
NAME P_ID
---- ------------------------------
A    L1147511
B    L1124411
B    L1745552
B    L5231242
C    L1124427
C    L1142322
C    L5223112
D    L4715442
D    L9914234
E    L1147329
E    L1147459
E    Test          --> "Test" is here because I didn't omit it in
                       WHERE clause (line #20)

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

As you can see, "Test" is still here. There *are* options to remove it, e.g. `where substr(p_id, 1, 1) = 'L'` (presuming all valid values begin with a capital letter `L`) or any other option. You didn't explain *why* should it be left out, so - I'll leave it to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex [**`[lL]\d{7}`**](https://regex101.com/r/BCLfVw/1) with [**`CONNECT BY`**](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries003.htm#SQLRF52332) for example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    TRIM(NAME) AS NAME,
    TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(P_ID, '[lL]\d{7}', 1, level)) AS P_ID
FROM
    test_table
CONNECT BY
    TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(P_ID, '[lL]\d{7}', 1, level)) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    NAME, P_ID;
```

Outputs

```
NAME    P_ID
A   L1147511
B   L1124411
B   L1745552
B   L5231242
C   L1124427
C   L1142322
C   L5223112
D   L4715442
D   L9914234
E   L1147329
E   L1147459
```

---

[**Find the full example here.**](https://dbfiddle.uk/YtqBoOg4)

Comment: This considers the codes have the length 7 and begin with L and does not consider the case when the code length may vary, having only the separators ,;/[ that determine where a code starts

Comment: @BogdanDincescu this is what I understand from the OP's regex `'^[Ll0-9]{8,8}'` and from the inputs

Answer (score 1):

This is an other way to do it using `regexp_substr connect by level` :

```
with rws as (
  select NAME, P_ID from test_table
),
CTE AS (
  select distinct NAME, regexp_substr (
           P_ID,
           '[^;,/\[]+',
           1,
           level
         ) value
  from   rws
  connect by level <= 
    length ( P_ID ) - length ( regexp_replace ( P_ID, '[;,/\[]' ) ) + 1
ORDER BY NAME
)
SELECT NAME, TRIM(replace(VALUE, '( Test)]', '')) as P_ID
FROM CTE;
```

Results :

```
NAME    P_ID
A   L1147511
B   L1124411
B   L1745552
B   L5231242
C   L1124427
C   L1142322
C   L5223112
D   L9914234
D   L4715442
E   L1147329
E   L1147459
```

The connect by level clause generates a row for each value. It finds how many values there are by:

Using replace `regexp_replace ( P_ID, '[;,/\[]' )` to remove all the separators from the string

Subtracting the length of the replaced string from the original to get the number of separators.

Add one to this result to get the number of values
The regexp_substr extracts each value using this regular expression: `[^;,/\[]+`

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/X4tedyaM)